# MySQL - how to use variable in where clause of cursor

Tags: mysql

I usually work with Oracle database and when creating stored procedures one can write cursors where the where clause can have a variable, value of which can be provided at run time.
How do you write something similar in mySQL

Something like

DECLARE myCursor cursor select col1 from table1 where col2 = &1;

OPEN myCursor ("NEW");

Comment: This feature is not supported in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You may use user-defined variable and/or local variable (including procedure parameters), both assigned externally and calculated internally, in the cursor definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc( {parameters} )
BEGIN
    DECLARE _id_ INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id FROM test WHERE val = {variable};
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
    BEGIN
        CLOSE cur;
    END;
    
    OPEN cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO _id_;
        SELECT _id_;
    END LOOP;
END
```

But you cannot to alter the parameter "on the fly" - after cursor is opened the changes in its parameters will be iglored (during the opening the cursor's text is fixed, the values instead of names are used in fixed text).

Hence when you need to alter dynamically assigned parameter then you must close and reopen the cursor.

[<kbd>**DEMO fiddle**</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9b00274b82ce127a1e1238fbe0035a0)